# How do you classify the critical points of non-autonomous differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider, for instance, the non-autonomous differential equation
$$y'=(y^2-1)(y-x).$$
Calling $f$ to the right side of the equation, we have that
$$f(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow y=\pm 1\vee y=x.$$
If we consider the second derivative of $y$,
$$y''=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=-(y^2-1),$$
since $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, then for points $(a,a)$, such that $-1<a<1$, we have $-(a^2-1)>0$ which would make them repulsive, and if $a<-1\vee a>1$, we would have $-(a^2-1)<0$ which would make them atractive.

But how to proceed in the cases where $a=\pm 1$ or $y=\pm 1$ for which $-(y^2-1)=0$? How to classify these points? Is it done by graphical analysis?

Comment: If $y = \pm 1$ (or $a = \pm 1$), then the function is constant (hence both a global max and min)! Note the the constant solutions satisfy the DE, and because the right hand side is a nice continuously differentiable polynomial, the [Picard Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) applies, so the constant solution is unique.

Comment: I guess my question is that if the equation was autonomous like $y'=y^2-1$, then you would have $y=\pm 1$ as critical points and, by a simple study of the sign of $y^2-1$, although being constant solutions, you would classify $y=-1$ as an attractive point (solution) and $y=1$ as a repulsive point (solution). In the non.autonomous case like the one I exhibited above could we conclude a similar behavior for $y=\pm1$?

Comment: Ah, I see. I confess that I'm not a DEs expert. I thought you were trying to characterise the critical points of the solutions, but I see I was a little mistaken. My intuition (for what little it's worth) is, away from the points $(1, 1)$ and $(-1, -1)$, you should be able to analyse stability along $y = \pm 1$ in a similar fashion to the autonomous $y' = y^2 - 1$, since near the point $(x_0, \pm 1)$, the factor $y - x$ does not differ in sign from $y - x_0$. But, hopefully someone more confident might provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! When I analyze the phase diagram of the DE, stability around $y=\pm 1$ is not clear to me. It looks like it changes along with the variation of $x$. I guess being non-autonomous means exactly that...